# How do I replace the setTimeout method in a typesafe manner?

Tags: javascript, typescript, type-safety

In my tests I want to replace the setTimeout method so that the tests run fast.

Originally I had the equivalent piece of code that used "any"... But of course eslint etc bleats.

I now have this piece of code which at last does not have any in it.

```
  let defaultTimeout: typeof globalThis.setTimeout;
  beforeEach(() => {
    defaultTimeout = global.setTimeout;
    globalThis.setTimeout = (callback: TimerHandler) => { (1)
      defaultTimeout(callback, 500);
    };
  })
```

However, I still get an error at globalThis.setTimeout

> TS2741: Property  **promisify**  is missing in type  (callback:
> TimerHandler) => void  but required in type  typeof setTimeout 
> timers.d.ts(161, 19):  **promisify**  is declared here.

I know that I can resolve this by using any and unknown... is there another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overriding functions like `setTimeout`, `setInterval`, `console.*` is bad practice. Why do you do it in that way? Did you consider using timer mocks?

I assume you use Jest or Vitest, anyway the logic is identical.

If all you want is to skip the timers, you could do

```js
jest.useFakeTimers();

// Your test code goes here...

expect(true).toEqual(true);

jest.runAllTimers();

jest.useRealTimers();
```

The `jest.runAllTimers();` line is the one doing the trick, "fast-forwarding" the timers, read more here: https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestrunalltimers

Comment: Yes, I have read that and I considered it. My problem is that I need to run the "timers" inside the code. I can't return and _then_ have the timers run as by then I have waited too long. And I need to run lots of them (timers I mean).

iow in the SIT I use setInterval to pause and I want the test to circumvent this so that the test does not take as long to run.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the impetus from @Tal Rofe I had another look:

I didn't realise I can just use jest to mock global functions... so this is my solution:

```
jest.useFakeTimers();
type TimeoutType = ReturnType<typeof globalThis.setTimeout>;
const spyOn = jest.spyOn(global, 'setTimeout');
spyOn.mockImplementation((callback: (args: void) => void): TimeoutType => {
  callback();
  return <TimeoutType>(<unknown>0); // timeout is actually a number!
});
```